# Max range between Bluetooth 5 LE device and a smartphones

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, bluetooth

What is the maximum range achievable between a Bluetooth 5 LE device and a smartphone? This would be assuming ideal outdoor condition with no obstacles etc.

The amount of data to be transferred is minimal at a few Boolean values per second, over and above the communication necessary for the connection between the devices.

I realise that the antenna design and power draw for the first device will also impact the range so please assume these are also optimal.

Comment: BLE’s performance in terms of acceptable path loss doesn’t depend on how much data you’re sending. The link occupancy affects power use of course.

Comment: Supposedly 100m. In reality it is highly variable.  It is not unusual to have a zillion BLE devices in the one area - in my office there is probably over 100 from TVs, mobile phones, headphones etc. These all compete for airspace. Which way the phone is pointing, how it is held etc all affect the signal strength. I get over 10m in an office area with pretty good reliability.